# Can the word 'motorist' also mean 'engine manufacturer'?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, synonyms

Can the word 'motorist' also mean 'engine manufacturer' ? The dictionaries I have consulted define motorist only as the one who drives an automotive vehicle. I've seen the word used in a tagline (supposedly proofed by an english linguist) that makes sense only if 'motorist' means 'engine
manufacturer'. So, I wonder whether it's a bad translation from a tagline in another language (would be french, in which "motoriste" means "engine manufacturer") or not.

In response to a comment asking for the tagline, it is *[company name],
the motorist of time*, and the company in question manufactures mechanical
watch movements. In my opinion, *[company name], the engine maker of time*
makes sense for such a company (as well as its french version, *..., le motoriste du temps*), whereas *..., the car driver of time* sounds funny, if motorist does indeed only mean car driver. I wonder how a native english speaker understands the tagline.

Comment: I suspect that your suspicion is correct.  "Motorist" means "one who operates a motor vehicle"; it has no sense meaning "one who manufactures motors".

Comment: See: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/motorist?s=t

Comment: I have never ever seen "motorist" used to mean "engine manufacturer".

Comment: The tagline could be some kind of joke or pun.  Could you add it to your question?

Answer (score 17):

The problem smelled of a French to English howler the moment I started reading, and before I got to the last line.

So many French words look easy to translate into English but mean something different or are nuanced differently.

*In England they eat eggs and lard for breakfast* is a classic schoolboy mistranslation. *Lard* is the French for *bacon*, whilst in English it is the animal fat that is used for cooking.

Anyway the *Oxford Hachette French - English Dictionary* defines ***motoriste*** as ***engine builder*** or ***mechanic***.

**In English a *motorist* is someone who drives a car.**

Comment: It can be as problematical going from English to French. I remember as a very young adult, sitting at dinner with a French family who offered me more food to eat. When I replied *merci, je suis plein* literally *thankyou but I'm full* it caused hoots of laughter, and I was red-faced with embarrassment when I was told it was a rather crude way (only used with animals) of saying *I'm pregnant*.

Comment: On a school trip to Germany, one of the Americans picked up a gift in the airport for their host family prominently labeled "Gift Pack" -- or, when interpreted as German, a "Poison Bundle."

Comment: As mentioned by WS2, *motoriste* is a good example of "false friend". In French, the only meaning of *motoriste* is *engine manufacturer*. When you look at examples in context provided by French-English translation dictionaries, the only translation of *motoriste* is *engine manufacturer*.

Comment: The Académie française are probably still regretting the demise of steam-powered cars, and having to change French *chauffeurs* into the Americanized *automobilistes*.